# Limiting Number of Predictions - R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a model that predicts whether a given team makes the playoffs in the NHL, based on a variety of available team stats.  However, I'm running into a problem.

I'm using R, specifically the caret package, and I'm having fairly good success so far, with one issue: I can't limit the the number of teams that are predicted to make the playoffs.

I'm using a categorical variable as the prediction -- Y or N.

For example, using the random forest method from the caret package,

```
rf_fit <- train(playoff ~ ., data = train_set, method = "rf")
rf_predict <- predict(rf_fit,newdata = test_data_playoffs)

mean(rf_predict == test_data_playoffs$playoff)
```

gives an accuracy of approximately 90% for my test set, but that's because it's overpredicting.  In the NHL, 16 teams make the playoffs, but this predicts 19 teams to make the playoffs.  So I want to limit the number of "Y" predictions to 16.

Is there a way to limit the number of possible responses for a categorical variable?  I'm sure there is, but google searching has given me limited success so far.

EDIT: Provide sample data which can be created with the following code:

```
set.seed(100) # For reproducibility 
data <- data.frame(Y = sample(1:10,32,replace = T)/10, N = rep(NA,32))
data$N <- 1-data$Y
```

This creates a data frame similar to what you get by using the "prob" option, where you have a list of probabilities for Y and N

```
pred <- predict(fit,newdata = test_data_playoffs, "prob")
```

Comment: Why dont you ignore/delete the three teams with the lowest probability of Y in your predicted list?

Comment: Exactly, don't predict yes/no, but take the probabilities and use the top 16.

Comment: Interesting, should work, thanks.  Slightly more work, but should work. I'll leave it open in case there's a way to do it exactly

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian  Good response.  Please write it up as an answer

Comment: If the OP (@PierreduPont) would like to post some sample data, I'd be more than happy to answer.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian Method for creating sample data posted.  It matches the type of data you get out of the type = "prob" option  in predict

Comment: @PierreduPont thats not a reproducible example...you have a training set and a test set.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I thought you were just going to demonstrate how to select the top n from the data set.  So I just gave the results from the prediction on the test set